# Image File upload with Django form using jQuery

Tags: jquery, python, django

I'm trying to allow users of my site to upload image files. The way I want to accomplish this is to use jQuery to upload the file to the server, parse the file's EXIF data if it has any data (namely, GeoLocation data). If the image file does not have the GeoLocation data, I want to ask the user for the data, then show a confirmation page. Otherwise, if I have the data, show the confirmation page with the data. Once the user confirms the data is correct, then the data is added to a Django model. The problems I am currently having are displaying the image on a confirmation page and having the form be submitted via jQuery and not as a usual POST. As you will see in the code, I have methods to get the data out that works when the file path is known, but currently I'm getting the error: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, InMemoryUploadedFile found. Here's code for reference (sorry, its a bit long):

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from photos.models import PhotoMessages

class PhotoUploadForm(forms.Form):
    """
    The form used to upload a user's photo
    """
    photo = forms.ImageField(label='Photo to upload', help_text='Must be a valid image', error_messages={'required': 'A photo is required'})
    legalAgreement = forms.BooleanField(label='', help_text=PhotoMessages.objects.filter(tag='Legal Agreement')[0].message, error_messages={'required': PhotoMessages.objects.filter(tag='Legal Agreement Error')[0].message})
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from photos.forms import PhotoUploadForm
from photos.models import PhotoMessages
from photos.utils import readexif, get_client_ip
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def uploadPhoto(request):
    """
    Creates the initial form for uploading a file and handles form errors and proper submission
    """
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
            form = PhotoUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES) # A form bound to the POST data
            if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
                # First, get the image location
                image = form.cleaned_data.get('photo')

                # TODO the above is a InMemoryUploadedFile
                # need to figure out how to use the data in that file, possibly by
                # saving its contents to a directory

                # then, get the exif data from the file
                dat = readexif(image)
                # uploaded time
                uploaded = datetime.now()
                # get the IP address from where the file was uploaded
                ip = get_client_ip(request)
                # get the user that uploaded the file
                user = request.user
                # if we have the geolocation data, show the user a confirmation page
                if 'lat' in dat:
                    # we have location info
                    return render(request, 'confirm.html', {
                        'img': image,
                        'lat': dat['lat'],
                        'lon': dat['lon'],
                        'taken': dat['taken'],
                        'uploaded': uploaded,
                        'ip': ip,
                        'user': user,
                        })
                # else:
                    # we need to request the location info

        else:
            form = PhotoUploadForm() # An unbound form

        return render(request, 'uploadPhoto.html', {
            'form': form,
        })
    else:
        return render(request, 'notLoggedIn.html', {
            'mesg': PhotoMessages.objects.filter(tag='User not logged in')[0].message,
            })
```

utils.py (utility functions for getting EXIF and other data):

```
import exifread
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser

# DateTime tags for when the image was taken
DT_TAGS = ["Image DateTime", "EXIF DateTimeOriginal", "EXIF DateTimeDigitized", "DateTime"]

def get_client_ip(request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')
    return ip


def readexif(f):
    """
    Method to read in exif data from an image
    returns a dictionary of the EXIF data found
    """
    ret = {}
    dt_value = None
    f.open('rb')
    ret['processed'] = False
    try:
        # read the file
        tags = exifread.process_file(f)

        ret['processed'] = True

        # handle time image taken
        for dt_tag in DT_TAGS:
            try:
                dt_value = "%s" % tags[dt_tag]
            except:
                continue
        if dt_value:
            ret['taken'] = exif_info2time(dt_value)

        # GeoLocation Data
        longitude = "%s" % tags['GPS GPSLongitude']
        longitude = longitude.strip('[]')
        latitude = "%s" % tags['GPS GPSLatitude']
        latitude = latitude.strip('[]')
        ret['lon'] = deg_min_sec_to_deg(longitude.split(','))
        ret['lat'] = deg_min_sec_to_deg(latitude.split(','))
        longRef = "%s" % tags['GPS GPSLongitudeRef']
        latRef = "%s" % tags['GPS GPSLatitudeRef']
        if longRef == 'W':
            ret['lon'] = -ret['lon']
        if latRef == 'S':
            ret['lat'] = -ret['lat']


    finally:
        f.close()

    return ret

def exif_info2time(ts):
    return dateutil.parser.parse(ts)


def deg_min_sec_to_deg2(deg, minutes, sec):
    return deg + minutes*(1.0/60) + sec * (1.0/3600)

def deg_min_sec_to_deg(arr):
    if "/" in arr[0]:
        degArr = arr[0].split("/")
        deg = float(degArr[0])/float(degArr[1])
    else:
        deg = float(arr[0])

    if "/" in arr[1]:
        minArr = arr[1].split("/")
        minutes = float(minutesArr[0])/float(minutesArr[1])
    else:
        minutes = float(arr[1])

    if "/" in arr[2]:
        secArr = arr[2].split("/")
        sec = float(secArr[0])/float(secArr[1])
    else:
        sec = float(arr[2])

    return deg_min_sec_to_deg2(deg, minutes, sec)
```

upload.js (currently this is commented out):

```
$( "#photoUpload" ).submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#myModalContent").html('Loading...');
    // console.log(event);
    $.post(event.target.action, $( "#photoUpload" ).serialize(), function(data) {
        $("#myModalContent").html(data);
    })
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
UPDATE 1/3 - I'm no longer having the problem of getting the data out of the file. Now, I just need to display the image with the obtained information on a page requesting additional information and then store the image and information received into my model to store into a database.

Comment: Please post the traceback for your error, too

Comment: @sk1p I've edited the post to include the traceback

Answer (score 1):

`form.cleaned_data['photo']` is not a filename, but an [`InMemoryUploadedFile`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/file-uploads/#uploadedfile-objects). Small files, [by default smaller than 2.5MB](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/http/file-uploads/#where-uploaded-data-is-stored), don't even have a file name; they are only held in memory. `InMemoryUploadedFile` is [a subclass of `File`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/files/file/#django.core.files.File), so instead of `f = open(fn, 'rb')`, you could do:

```
def readexif(f):
    f.open('rb')
    tags = exifread.process_file(f)
    # ... do more stuff with tags
```

and pass the `File` from your form directly, just like you are currently doing:

```
# ...
dat = readexif(image)
# ...
```

That should at least correct the error you are currently getting.

Comment: Upon making this change, I did some testing uploading a file with known GeoLocation data, but the readexif function does not find any of that data. I think this is because the file is an `InMemoryUploadedFile`, and the `exifread.process_file()` method can't handle that file type, but I may be mistaken. Thoughts?

Comment: Is the file content correctly transferred? Can you see it in the network tab of your browser's development tools?

Comment: @rwb7041 also, you can try and eliminate the js as an error source - try to submit the form without any javascript and see if it works (make sure to set `enctype`)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I did comment out the javascript, so that's not running. In the network tab of my browser (Chrome), I see the POST request. When I click on it, I see under Request Payload the image file name that I uploaded with the Content-type being image/jpeg

Comment: I've also went ahead and included the content of the form template (uploadPhoto.html) just for reference

Comment: Just for debugging, you can try and put the image into a `io.BytesIO` before passing it to exifread: `buf = BytesIO(f.read())` where `f` is the `InMemoryUploadedFile` (also, you can verify that the length of the buffer is not zero, `assert len(buf.read()) != 0` but remember to do `buf.seek(0)` afterwards)

Comment: That did not work. I get an error saying BytesIO does not have an open method

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44467/discussion-between-sk1p-and-rwb7041)